# Вывод стандартных постов и пользовательских. Позиции рандомно. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть созданная страница - баннер с двумя инпутами. В одном ссылка, в другом рисунок.

Есть страница поста, в конце которого выводится три поста из раздела баннеры рандомно, а остальные три из обычных публикаций, тоже выводится рандомно.
По отдельности с ними проблем нет. Вывожу.

Но поставлена задача: выводить их рандомно. Привожу код чтобы было более понятно.

```
$posts1 = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'banner', 'orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3));
$posts2 = get_posts(array('orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3, 'category'=>-9, 'exclude'=>get_the_ID()));
$posts = array_merge($posts1, $posts2);
//$posts = get_posts(array('orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>6));
foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icerik-post">
            <div class="post-image">
                <div class="img-block">
                    <a href="<?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-image')); ?></a>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail() ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-icerik">
                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo(types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                <div class="info">
                    <p><span class="ago"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' önce '; ?></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata();
```

Необходимо:

Первое: если вывод из пользовательского раздела "баннер" заголовок и картинка с ссылкой должна выводиться, а из стандартных постов не должно выводится. Если пост из раздела записи - тогда наоборот.

Второе: позиция должна быть рандомно. То есть, "'orderby'=> rand". Пробовал по разному, использовал функцию "shuffle()" но при ее использовании у меня неизвестная ошибка и все падает. Использовал эту функцию таким образом: "$posts = shuffle($posts);"

P.S. Я новичок, только на старте WordPress и php. Хозяин наотрез отказывается от плагинов. Говорит, строчи как хочешь. Недели 2 мучаюсь.

Подправьте как надо, плиз.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу перемешивания. Функция перемешивает массив по месту, а возвращает true или false, в зависимости от результата работы. Правильный ее вызов такой:

```
shuffle($posts);
```

Результирующий код:

```
$posts1 = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'banner', 'orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3));
$posts2 = get_posts(array('orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3, 'category'=>-9, 'exclude'=>get_the_ID()));
$posts = array_merge($posts1, $posts2);
shuffle($posts);
foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icerik-post">
            <div class="post-image">
                <div class="img-block">
                    <a href="<?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-image')); ?></a>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail() ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-icerik">
                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo(types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                <div class="info">
                    <p><span class="ago"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' önce '; ?></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata();
```

По поводу вывода нужной обертки поста. Я не совсем понял из вопроса, как надо, но примерно так получается:

```
$posts1 = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'banner', 'orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3));
$posts2 = get_posts(array('orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3, 'category'=>-9, 'exclude'=>get_the_ID()));
$posts = array_merge($posts1, $posts2);
shuffle($posts);
foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icerik-post">
            <?php
            if ($post->post_type == 'banner') {
                ?>
                <div class="post-image">
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <a href="<?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-image')); ?></a>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail() ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
                ?>
                <div class="post-icerik">
                    <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo(types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                    <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                    <div class="info">
                        <p><span class="ago"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' önce '; ?></span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata();
```

Смотрите на операторы if, где 'banner' и 'post' и поменяйте их местами, если надо.

Comment: я в шоке. я писал этот "shuffle()" уменя не работал, ваше перекопировал сразу сработало ))

по поводу второго:

если запись из раздела "банер"
вместо функции <pre>"the_permalink()"</pre> в теге <а> должно быть " <pre>echo(types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres'))</pre>" а вместо "echo get_the_post_thumbnail()" должно быть "echo (types_render_field( 'banner-image'))"


если из раздела стандартных записей тогда наоборот.


огромное спс. первое стаботало. теперь бы с вторым разобраться

Comment: Вы писали $posts = shuffle($posts); и присваивали массиву постов значение true или false.

Comment: в комментариях код, а тем более кусками, писать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью рабочий код. Думаю, многим пригодится у кого есть блог. Проблему решил KAGG Design @kagg-design

```
<?php
$posts1 = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'banner', 'orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3));
$posts2 = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'post', 'orderby'=> rand, 'numberposts'=>3, 'category'=>-9, 'exclude'=>get_the_ID()));
$posts = array_merge($posts1, $posts2);
shuffle($posts);
foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icerik-post">
            <?php
            if ($post->post_type == 'banner') {
                ?>
            <div class="post-image">
                <div class="img-block">
                    <a href="<?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php echo (types_render_field( 'banner-image')); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-icerik">
                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo(types_render_field( 'banner-url-adres')); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                <div class="info">
                    <p><span class="ago"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' önce '; ?></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
                ?>
            <div class="post-image">
                <div class="img-block">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail() ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-icerik">
                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h5>
                <div class="info">
                    <p><span class="ago"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' önce '; ?></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div><?php } wp_reset_postdata();?>
```